Is there a workaround for the function Startswith() since it is not delegable for D365 FO?
In PowerApps, all search functions for Dynamics 365 FO are non-delegable, which means I am unable to filter the gallery using the search bar input.Is there a workaround for this limitation?
All of there functions are not delegable:
-StartsWith
-EndsWith
-In
-Left
-Right
-Search
-Mid
-Len
https://manueltgomes.com/reference/delegable-functions-reference/#dynamics
If(
    !IsBlank(tbx_search.Text);
    Filter(
        CustomersV3;
        Customergroup = "F" && StartsWith(AccountNum; tbx_search.Text)
    );
    Filter(
        CustomersV3;
        Customergroup = "F"
    )
)

Currently, I am limited to using AccountNum= tbx_search.Text, which requires me to enter the entire number into the search bar.

Solved like this:
SortByColumns(
Search(
Filter(
CustomersV3;
Customergroup = "F"
);
tbx_search.Text;
AccountNum
);"CustomerAccount";
SortOrder.Ascending
);
